# merging columns from two different data frame

Tags: python, pandas, replace, merge, concatenation

I have two different dataframe as shown in the images below. I will like to merge column (C-ORG_PC) in the first dataframe with column (C-ORG_PC) in the second dataframe such that when the SAMPFROM column in both dataframe are equal, It will replace the -99 value at that point in the first dataframe with the corresponding value in the second dataframe.

data1:

| SAMPFROM | SAMPTO | C-ORG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | -99 |
| 5 | 10 | -99 |
| 10 | 15 | -99 |
| 15 | 20 | -99 |
| 20 | 25 | -99 |
| 25 | 30 | -99 |
| 30 | 35 | -99 |
| 35 | 40 | -99 |
| 40 | 45 | -99 |

data2:

| SAMPFROM | SAMPTO | C-ORG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 2.5 |
| 20 | 40 | 7 |
| 40 | 60 | 7 |
| 60 | 80 | 9 |

```
 LIST1=list(data1['SAMPFROM'])
LIST2=list(data2['SAMPFROM'])
values=[]
for i in LIST1:
 for j in LIST2:
    if i==j:
        values.append(i)
for k in values:
 for q in data2['SAMPFROM']:
    if k==q:
        data1['new']=data2['CO3_pct_BESTEL']
```

Comment: include the data as text and not as images

Comment: @onyambu done. Can you help out with the way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
df1 = data1.set_index('SAMPFROM')
df1.update(data2.set_index('SAMPFROM')['C-ORG'])
df1.reset_index()

   SAMPFROM  SAMPTO  C-ORG
0         0       5    2.5
1         5      10  -99.0
2        10      15  -99.0
3        15      20  -99.0
4        20      25    7.0
5        25      30  -99.0
6        30      35  -99.0
7        35      40  -99.0
8        40      45    7.0
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is at the point where SAMPFROM in the first df is equal to SAMPFROM in df2, it should update. ie when sampfrom is at point 20, the value is -99, I want it to update it with with the value (2.5) at point 20 in df2